# Volumetric Dilatation Rate, Material derivatives, and Divergence

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, density, continuum-mechanics, volume

in class we derived the following relationship:
$$\frac{1}{V}\frac{dV}{dt}= \nabla \cdot \vec{v}$$
This was derived though the analysis of linear deformation for a fluid-volume, where:
$$dV = dV_x +dV_y + dV_z$$
I understood the derived relation as:
$$\frac{1}{V}V'(t) = \nabla \cdot \vec{v}$$
However, my professor recently told me that the $d/dt$ operator before V, stood for the material derivative and not the common derivative. I am very confused as to how is that the case, given that we did an infinitesimal analysis of linear deformation, in a way I could call analogous to any other infinitesimal analysis that results in the common derivative.

I also tried deriving the equation by taking the material derivative of $V$, and dividing by $V$:
$$ \frac{1}{V}\frac{DV}{Dt} = \frac{1}{V}\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{V}(\vec{v} \cdot gradV)$$

but I was unable to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The continuity equation reads $$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+v\centerdot \nabla \rho+\rho \nabla \centerdot v=0$$where $\rho$ is the fluid density.  Dividing this by $\rho $ gives $$\frac{1}{\rho}\left(\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+v\centerdot \nabla \rho\right)+\nabla \centerdot v=0$$But, since the density is the inverse of the specific volume V, we have $$\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}+v\centerdot \nabla V\right)=\frac{1}{V}\frac{DV}{Dt}=\nabla \centerdot v$$

Comment: That is a very nice explanation, thanks a lot!  I was wondering if the divergence term should have a negative sign next to it since it was positive on the RHS? Or is the sign arbitrary in this case?

Comment: No.  $\ln{\rho}=-\ln{V}$

Comment: So since $$1/\rho = \nu = V/m $$, then $$\frac{1}{\rho} (\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \vec{v} \cdot \nabla \rho)+ \nabla \cdot \vec{v} =  V (\frac{\partial 1/V}{\partial t} + \vec{v} \cdot \nabla (1/V)) +\nabla \cdot \vec{v}  = \frac{D(1/V)}{Dt} + \nabla \cdot \vec{v}= 0 $$ and then do you integrate? Or am I doing this incorrectly.

Comment: No.  You're missing a minus sign.  $$\frac{D\ln{\rho}}{Dt}=-\frac{D\ln{V}}{Dt}$$. Please review differentiation of a quotient.

Comment: How do you get those logarithmic terms? Do you replace 1/V as dlnV/dt ? I remember the quotient rule, I am unsure as to how you are applying it in this case, I took mass as constant so that I could factor it out and then cancel it in order to have everything in terms of V. I am not quite sure I am following what you mean.

Comment: $d(1/V)=-dV/V^2$ so $Vd(1/V)=-\frac{dV}{V}$ so $\frac{1}{\rho}d\rho=-\frac{1}{V}dV$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118590/discussion-between-chet-miller-and-rsm).